# FactoryGirl model's id => nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I have model:

```
class CreateStores < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :stores do |t|
      t.integer :admin_id
      t.string :name
      t.string :subdomain
      t.string :linked_domain

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class Api::Be::UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  setup do
    @admin = FactoryGirl.create :admin

    @store = FactoryGirl.create :store
    @store.ug_default = UgDefault.new
    @store.save

    Rails::logger.debug "HERE: #{@store.id}"

    @customer = FactoryGirl.create :customer
    @customer.userable_id = @store.id
    @customer.save
  end
```

In logs I see that `@store.id` equals nil. What's the problem?

Comment: How about your model?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not getting saved. With your logger, output if there are any errors on the model:

```
Rails.logger.debug "#{@store.errors.inspect}"
```

Look for messages at the end of the output.

Comment: #<ActiveModel::Errors:0xb61e2e84 @base=#<Store id: nil, admin_id: nil, name: "string-5", subdomain: "string-6", linked_domain: "string-7", created_at: "2014-04-02 13:11:08", updated_at: "2014-04-02 13:11:08">, @messages={}> where are no errors, right?

Comment: Correct, messages hash is empty. Are you returning false in any before_save callbacks on the model? Using the same attributes in rails console are you able to create an instance?